# How to make one component of two different but similar by passing a value?

Tags: angular

I have a menu that routes clicking to a named outlet presenting submenus. Each submenu is a separate component. After a clean-up I noticed that the only difference between those submenus is a single index to pick captions and urls from. Naturally, I'd like to get rid of all but one such submenu component to lower the complexity of my project.

HTML

```xml
<div class="nav-sub">
  <div *ngFor="let menu of menus;"
       (click)="onClick(menu,menu.link)"
       [ngClass]="{'active':menu.active}"
       routerLink="{{menu.link}}">{{menu.caption}}</div>
  </div>
```

TS

```js
@Component({ selector: "submenu1", templateUrl: "./submenu1.component.html", ... })
export class Submenu1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
  onClick(target, link) { this.menus.forEach(_ => _.active = _ === target);  }
  private menus = Settings.menus[1].subs;
}
```

Routing

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "submenu1", component: Submenu1Component, outlet: "menus" },
  { path: "submenu2", component: Submenu2Component, outlet: "menus" },

  { path: "linky-from-submenu-1a", component: SomeComponent1a },
  { path: "linky-from-submenu-1b", component: SomeComponent1b },
  ...
];
```

Is it possible? How?

I've tried to play around with using different paths and trying to make the router tell me the ID targeted but the complexity grew dramatically and I suspect that I was doing more harm than good (i.e. increasing, not lowering, the complexity).

I also made some other attempts but I dislike the general thought there (i.e. a global holder of info for what's been clicked imposing the right texts/links to be in the submenu bar. Using the same HTML-template but different TS-file was a good idea for decreasing the file number but still... It feels like there's an opportunity to gain skills by doing it the most proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, Event, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";
import { SubMenu, Settings } from "../navbar.model";

@Component({ ... })
export class SubmenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let url : string = router.url;
        let index : number = getIndexFromUrl(url);
        this.menus = Settings.menus[index].subs;            
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  private menus: SubMenu[];

}
```

Routing

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "submenu1", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  { path: "submenu2", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  ...
];
```

Comment: This works fine :), I would prefer the approach with route parameters mainly because to me it looks cleaner. If I read that code in 1 year it would be easier to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) service and subscribe to the [url](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#url) observable. Based on the value you get there you decide on what data to load.

Another approach would be to use params in the path, so you would have something like '*submenu/1*' and '*submenu/2*' where 1 and 2 are an 'id' parameter and in the activated route you read them from the [params](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#params) Observable. In this way it's more easily extendable and you could use something more meaningful for the param values.

Routes config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "submenu/:menuId", component: SubmenuComponent, outlet: "menus" },
  ...
];
```

And then in the SubmenuComponent you can handle the OnInit lifecycle event and fetch the param:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params
            .subscribe(({ menuId }) => { /* load data based on menuId */ });
}
```

*this.route* is an instance of the ActivatedRoute service which you can inject in constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

Comment: Check out my answer below. I prefer the first approach that you mention. What's your take on the comparison between that and the second approach that you suggested?